# how to get the sum form 2 till 12 rolldie?

Tags: javascript

Write a script to simulate the rolling of two dice. The script should use Math.random to roll the first die and again to roll the second die. The sum of the two values should then be calculated.
[Note: Since each die can show an integer value from 1 to 6, the sum of the values will vary from 2 to 12, with 7 being the most frequent sum, and 2 and 12 the least frequent sums].
Your program should roll the dice 5000 times. Use a one-dimensional array to tally the number of times each possible sum appears. Display the results in an HTML5 table.

I have only the sum can anyone tell me how to get the sum of roll die form 2 till 12 in a table

```js
    var total = [ , , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var dice1;
    var dice2;
    for (var x = 1; x <= 5000; x++)
    {
    dice1 = rollDie();
    dice2 = rollDie();
    ++total[dice1+ dice2];
    }
    outputResults();
    function rollDie()
    {
    return Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
    }
    function outputResults()
    {
    document.write( "<table border = \"1\">" );
    document.write("<tr><th width = '100'>Sum of Dice" +"<th width = \"200\">Total Times Rolled</tr>" );
    for ( var i = 2; i < total.length; i++ )
    document.write( "<tr><td>" + i + "<td>" +total[ i ] + "</tr>" );
    document.write( "</table>" )
    document.write( "<br>" );
    document.write( "<br>" );
    document.write( "<table border = \"1\">" );
    document.write("<tr><th width = '100'>Sum of Dice" +"<th width = \"200\">Total Times Rolled</tr>" );
    for ( var i = 2; i < total.length; i++ )
    document.write( "<tr><td>" + i + "<td>" +total[ i ] + "</tr>" );
    document.write( "</table>" );
    }
```

```html
    <p id="jareb"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var total = [,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var count = [,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

function write(){
  var html="";
  for(var i=2; i<=12; i++){
    html += ("The Sum of "+i+" occurred :"+count[i]+" Times and Total : " + total[i] + "<br/>");
  }
  
  document.write(html);
}


function roll(){
  var d1 = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
  var d2 = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
  count[d1+d2]++;
  total[d1+d2] += d1+d2;
}






for(i=1;i<=5000;i++)
  roll();

write();
```

```html
This is the result!
```

Comment: this what i want The Sum of 2 occurred :128 Times
The Sum of 3 occurred :311 Times
The Sum of 4 occurred :397 Times
The Sum of 5 occurred :544 Times
The Sum of 6 occurred :703 Times
The Sum of 7 occurred :839 Times
The Sum of 8 occurred :679 Times
The Sum of 9 occurred :550 Times
The Sum of 10 occurred :409 Times
The Sum of 11 occurred :295 Times
The Sum of 12 occurred :145 Times
@Serhat MERCAN

Comment: How  to make it @Serhat MERCAN

Comment: If u do not mind i have another question may i ask?@Serhat MERCAN

Comment: Lets try, may be I can help :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through every sum in `total` and add them together:

```
var sumOfAllDice = 0;

for(int i=2; i<=12; i++) {
   sumOfAllDice += total[i];
}

document.write('<p>'+sumOfAllDice+'</p>');
```

Comment: @FarooqFarooq this is just the calculation, once you have the value it's up to you to display it or output it. I updated my answer to include an example